# Is it possible to enable emojis for specific columns of specific tables?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, emoji, utf8mb4

First, I would like to assure you that I have done my "homework" and have read [this](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/29/supporting-new-emojis-on-ios-6), [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4), [this](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/05/how-to-store-emoji-in-a-rails-app-with-a-mysql-database/) and [this](https://slashdot.io/blog/adding-emoji-support-to-your-blog-948181198). Also, [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446440/how-to-support-emojis-with-flourish) of my former questions is closely related to this one, but in that question I am dealing about flourishlib's compatibility issues with utf8mb4. This question deals with a deeper level. Let's suppose that I have several tables and I want to modify just a few columns to have utf8mb4 encoding, to preserve some storage space and performance after the change. If I changed the whole database to have an encoding of utf8mb4, then its size would increase with 33%, which will affect its performance badly as well. So, we have selected four columns from three different tables to support emojis. These are:

- `users.bio` (tinytext, utf8_general_ci)
- `questions.question` (longtext, utf8_general_ci)
- `questions.answer` (longtext, ut8_general_ci)
- `comments.comment` (tinytext, utf8_general_ci)

As a result, my action plan is as follows:

1. Create a backup of the database
2. Run these commands:

```sql
alter table comments change comment comment tinytext character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
alter table users change bio bio tinytext character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
alter table questions change question question longtext character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
alter table questions change answer answer longtext character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Expectations:

- this should make the specified columns use utf8mb4 instead of utf8
- existent data will be correctly converted to utf8mb4, that is, previous texts will be preserved and the users will be able to correctly read their content
- other columns will not be changed
- queries involving the affected tables will be slower

Are my expectations accurate? Do I need to change the connection? Thanks

Comment: Weird... apparently SO's Markdown doesn't support having a code block immediately following a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need utf8mb4 in any columns that are storing Chinese.

In `VARCHAR(...)` utf8mb4, each "character" takes 1-4 bytes.  No 33% increase.
On the other hand, `CHAR(10) utf8mb4` is always allocated 40 bytes.

You do need to establish that your client is talking utf8mb4, not just utf8.  That comes in some parameter in the connection or with `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.

If you need to automate the `ALTERs`, it is pretty easy to generate them via a SELECT into information_schema.

**Addenda**

Expectations 1-3:  Yes.

Expectation 4 (queries involving the affected tables will be slower) -- processing will be essentially the same speed.

Comment: Rick, I have no business with Chinese characters. As I have described in my question we are talking about emojis. Also, your remark about varchar's size not increasing is invalid. Imagine a 10-character long varchar stored in utf8. That would take 30 bytes. Now, imagine a 10-character long varchar stored in utf8mb4. That would take 40 bytes.33% increase. Also, if you read the question again, you will see that types involved are tinytext and longtext. I need 4 alters, no need to automate them.

Comment: Your answer does not really address the question. I would really like to accept it, but you need to make edits to make sure it addresses the question. In the meantime I have resolved the issue, so I will either accept and answer or write my own.

Comment: It seems that your argument about varchars is valid, but it does not affect this question where there is no varchar involved.

Comment: Text _without_ emojis will take exactly the same space in `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` for `utf8` as for `ut8mb4`.  (And I answered the 'expectations')

Comment: OK, the Adenda made your answer THE answer, thanks. I will not write a separate answer here.